# Toggle classes in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, menu, font-awesome

**Hello.
Here is my code:**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("b").click(function() {
        $(strong).toggleClass("show");
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    .hide {
      display: none;
    }
    .show {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="hide">Some content here.</div>
  <b class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></b>
</body>

</html>
```

**I try to make a menu with a FontAwesome icon. When it is cliked, the menu contained in "hide" div show. It doesn't work. Help please.**

Comment: `strong` is undefined

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`$.fn.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/),as it looks from immediately preceding sibling.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("b").click(function() {
    $(this).prev('div').toggleClass("show hide");
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hide">Some content here.</div>
<b class="fa fa-bars fa-2x">strong</b >
```